# Cómo eliminar los registros que no estan en el resultado de una consulta

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta

```
select 
CodigoEmpresa,CodigoArticulo,stock, 
MAX(fechamodificacion)fechamodificacion 
from TPivote
group by CodigoEmpresa,CodigoArticulo,stock
```

Que me retorna los articulos modificados mas recientemente, como puedo eliminar los que no forman parte del resultado de esa consulta, seguro que es la mar de sencillo, pero no consigo hacerlo correctamente no se si existe algo como NOT MAX.
Grácias.

Comment: Probaste con un not in????

Comment: Esa consulta te retorna la última fecha de modificación de cada articulo, empresa y stock, no los artículos modificados mas recientemente. Creo que la mejor manera de que alguien te pueda ayudar, es que pongas un ejemplo de la tabla que tienes, unos valores, y luego lo que esperas que retorne la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice el comentario de Javi, tu consulta no entrega las últimas filas modificadas, así que debes tener cuidado con eso. Primero, te aconsejaría hacer una consulta para ver que estás teniendo los resultados que quieres:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CodigoEmpresa, CodigoArticulo, Stock 
                               ORDER BY FechaModificacion DESC)
    FROM TPivote
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
;
```

Una vez validad esa información, puedes hacer una consulta para borrar las filas que no pertenecen al resultado anterior:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CodigoEmpresa, CodigoArticulo, Stock 
                               ORDER BY FechaModificacion DESC)
    FROM TPivote
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
;
```